# How to implement custom callback action in SwiftUI? Similar to onAppear functionality

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have custom **ActionView** with two buttons: **Car** and **Bike**. When these buttons tapped I need that in the **MainView** modifiers **onCarTap**/**onBikeTap** will be triggered.

With my current implementation here is error:

- Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
- Value of tuple type 'Void' has no member 'onBikeTap'

Source code:

```
struct ActionView: View {
    // Callback for button taps
    var onCarTap: (() -> Void)?
    var onBikeTap: (() -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                onCarTap?()
            }, label: {
                Text("Car")
            })
            Button(action: {
                onBikeTap?()
            }, label: {
                Text("Bike")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking for solution like this:

```
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ActionView()
            .onCarTap({})
            .onBikeTap({ })
    }
}
```

It is possible to implement in this way:

```
    ActionView(onCarTap: {
        print("on car tap")
    }, onBikeTap: {
        print("on bike tap")
    })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare a modifier for your purpose like the following.

```
extension ActionView {
    func onCarTap(_ handler: @escaping () -> Void) -> ActionView {
        var new = self
        new.onCarTap = handler
        return new
    }
}
```

In addition, if you prefer to hide the handler property with `private` or `fileprivate` to prevent it from being accessed directly, you have to declare a designated `init` which accepts parameters for its properties except one for the handler.

Comment: "except one for the handler": this was the final hint I needed, as it is impossible to override the handler a second time, even if it is a State wrapped property. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have the following View:

```
struct ActionView: View {
    var onCarTapAction: (() -> Void)?
    var onBikeTapAction: (() -> Void)?

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                onCarTapAction?()
            }, label: {
                Text("Car")
            })
            Button(action: {
                onBikeTapAction?()
            }, label: {
                Text("Bike")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

You can create an extension:

```
extension ActionView {
    func onCarTap(action: @escaping (() -> Void)) -> ActionView {
        ActionView(onCarTapAction: action, onBikeTapAction: onBikeTapAction)
    }

    func onBikeTap(action: @escaping (() -> Void)) -> ActionView {
        ActionView(onCarTapAction: onCarTapAction, onBikeTapAction: action)
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ActionView()
            .onCarTap {
                print("onCarTap")
            }
            .onBikeTap {
                print("onBikeTap")
            }
    }
}
```